# read json file key value pair with space in value

Tags: jq

getting new line value while parsing json file with space in value from shell script

```json
{
  "KAFKASTORE_SASL_JAAS_CONFIG": "software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMLoginModule required;",
  "CLASSPATH": "/usr/share/java/aws/*"
}
```

with

```sh
test.sh script file
#!/bin/sh
for dir in "$home"/*; do
  for s in $(cat $dir | jq -r "to_entries|map(\"\(.key)=\(.value|tostring)\")|.[]" ); do
       export $s
  done
done
```

error

> KAFKASTORE_SASL_JAAS_CONFIG=software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMLoginModule
> required; ./jq.sh: line 20: export: `required;': not a valid
> identifier

Comment: Maybe you want to remove all the inner quotes and backslashes from the jq filter. It would then at least generate valid JSON.

Comment: could you share modified syntax, i tried and it didn't work

Comment: `$s` is split on arbitrary whitespace, not just newlines. You need to iterate over the output of `jq` line by line and call `export "$s"` for each line `$s`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work :

```
#!/bin/bash
 
for file in "$home"/*; do
  while read -r s; do
       export "$s"
  done < <(jq -r 'to_entries|map("\(.key)=\(.value)")[]' "$file")
done
```